# PowerShell:Download a file from URL with 257 chars and 404 returned

Tags: powershell

I tried to download a file from a url which has 257 characters,but the following error is returned:

> Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."

When I copy the URL to firefox or IE, I can download that file. then I tried to download a file from the same website but whose URL is short, I can download it successfully with Powershell.
Does anybody find the similar issue before? Could you pls share how to solve it?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Don't suppose this is a public site where you can share the url you are trying

Comment: 257 in total or 257 between two slashes (/)? Does [this link](http://46.38.245.27/stackoverflow/1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890.html) (255 for the file name, but longer in total) work? I can't create a longer path on my Linux ;-)

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: I asked our IT administrator to do something, then I can download the file now. Thanks a lot for all replys.

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced the exact same issue and this is how I resolved it. Thought it would help someone who comes to this thread later.

In my case, the reason for the exception was incorrect URL due to a parameter I added to the URL. Something like this:
`https://yourserverurl/archive-$OS.zip`

I was using a parameter in the URL for the Operating System. And I was getting the `$OS` argument wrong.

Therefore, the two reasons I can think of when this error occurs:

1. The file cannot be downloaded without authentication. But that would probably throw a 401.
2. The URL is incorrect. Maybe due to some parametrization as in my case.

Hope this helps!